# How to read a web file protected with .htaccess from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .htaccess, web

I need to access a XML file located in a secured location on a web server. The security of the file is done using htaccess.
How can I read from VB.NET (or any .NET) this file, providing the necessary credentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you need to supply a username and password.

To do this, set a `Credentials` object on the `HttpWebRequest`. See the documentation for more information and an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to retrieve the file, supply it with a [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) object like so:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient() With {
    .Credentials = New NetworkCredentials("MyUserName", "MyPassword")
}
```